# Get get part of list after certain value

Tags: c#

I have got a simple question I am having a list:

```
List<string> test = new List<string> {"one", "two", "three", "four"}
```

Now I want to take for example value "three" and get all elements after it, so it would be looking like:

```
List<string> test = new List<string> {"three", "four"}
```

But we do not know where list end so it can be list of many elements and we can not define end as const.

Is it possible?

Comment: I *think* I understood your question, but if my answer doesn't address what you're actually trying to do, please clarify it.

Comment: Note that there's been definite confusion about what you're trying to achieve. A [mcve] would help, where the sample creates a list and then passes it and any other appropriate input to a method which you're struggling to implement. That would make the condition easier to understand.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for `SkipWhile` from LINQ:

```
test = test.SkipWhile(x => x != "three").ToList();
```

That will skip everything until (but not including) the "three" value, then include everything else. It then converts it to a list again.

Comment: Won't this include any values equal to 3 after the first occurrence? So if the sequence was "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "three", "two", wouldn't it include the 2nd "three"?

Comment: @sr28 This method should skip until it finds first occurence of "three"

Comment: @m.rogalski - I get that bit. My first comment was worded wrong. What I meant was, does it only do this for the first occurrence? So if there was a second occurrence of "three", would it then stop there and not include anything after the second occurrence?

Comment: @sr28 from your example `{ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "three", "two" }` it will skip `{ "one", "two" }` and return `{ "three", "four", "five", "three", "two" }` Making it more clearer it will skip only until it finds first occurence and then it takes all of the rest.

Comment: @sr28: No, it wouldn't stop. `SkipWhile` just skips until the first time the condition isn't met, and then includes everything else.

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you

```
var list2 = test.Skip(2).Take(test.Count).ToList();
```

or better

```
var list3 = test.Skip(2).ToList();
```

Without LINQ it could be done something like this

```
List<string> outtest = new List<string>();
bool drty = false;
foreach(string st in test)
{
    if(st == "three") //or whatever is the input.
        drty = true;

    if(drty)
        outtest.Add(st);
}
```

Comment: That: a) won't compile; b) relies on knowing the index of the element needed; c) uses `Take` for no obvious reason...

Comment: a) now it compiles, b) yes that is correct, c) removed it in edit.

Comment: Why are you using "two" as input, when the question talks about getting all the values from "three"? The question isn't great, but it does look like if you were writing a method to do this, the inputs would be the list and the value "three".

Answer (score 0):

Since you assign the filtered list back to initial one, then just *remove* first items up to `"three"` one:

```
int count = test.IndexOf("three");

test.RemoveRange(0, count < 0 ? test.Count : count);
```

This implementation doesn't create additional list, but modifies existing one.